# userDefined Checked Exception Handling

Tags: java

**What is the benefit of defining a User Defined Checked Exception ?** I mean If we look into the real life project..we can not deploy our build without resolving all compile time exception.So in this scenario , User defined Runtime Exception can be justified...but how can we benefited from creating User Defined Checked Exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up terminology here. There is a Java class called `RuntimeException` which is unchecked. This doesn't mean that any exception that occurs at runtime is unchecked. In fact any Java exception occurs at runtime. It's the way to indicate a runtime error. Of course there are also compile time errors but I wouldn't call them exceptions.

Checked exception simply means that you have to handle it if it is thrown. Be it a try/catch or rethrowing. If you don't do so you'll get a compiler error. Handling unchecked exception is optional, but you can do it the same way.

When declaring your user defined exception, ask yourself if it's an error you'll be expecting and which you want to be handled by the caller. In my experience, making custom exceptions unchecked is very rare.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andre for your input.